# Ubuntu 14.10 no GUI or term login

Tags: boot

I have updated yesterday my Ubuntu 14.10 installation with apt-get dist-upgrade.

I was working all afternoon and after that I have rebooted computer. Once done it, lightdm doesn't starts (only gnome logo) and I can not view any of Ctrl + Shift + [1-6] terminals (cursor is blinking).

I have read a lot of posts with no success:

- nividia/intel conflicts (I have a laptop with an Intel graphic card)
- I have enabled nomodeset and tried all this options [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)
- I have repaired grub
- I can load recovery/livecd/windows and mount partitions and network without problem
- I have all packages and system updated

Here my [logs](http://pastebin.com/7jntD4Bm). X11 not shows any error or problem, is loading all needed drivers without problem.

How can I raise the level of debug?

[SOLVED]

I can't add a solution (low reputation), then I post here how to fix:

1) In grub menu, go to **Advanced options for Ubuntu** and then to **recovery mode** on last kernel

2) Select **root** option

3) Mount filesystem as rw: `mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdaX /` when X is your root partition

4) Edit file */etc/default/grub* with this line:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet init=/lib/systemd/systemd"`

5) update grub with: `update-grub2`

6) reboot and enjoy :)

More info here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2226708

Comment: 14.10 is a development version of Ubuntu, and as such, is not supported here.