# Enable typing in passphrase textbox after Ubuntu reboot (14.10)

Tags: virtualbox, encryption, 14.10

My Ubuntu VirtualBox VM upgraded itself two days ago to 14.10.

Now whenever I reboot the text on the enter the passphrase screen is clipped on the edges and I cannot type at all in the textbox (using the mouse, or tab, or enter, or any key).

However, if I manually reboot the machine a second time from VirtualBox the screen displays 'Fast TSC calibration failed' briefly and then the passphrase screen displays correctly and I can type.  Always twice to get it to work.

What should do I do to fix this?  It was working fine before the upgrade.

(I've tried running all the commands in this answer already: [(Statement) "Ubuntu 14.10 won't work because black screen" solution described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541939/statement-ubuntu-14-10-wont-work-because-black-screen-solution-described-he))

Answer (score 0):

If I reset the VM at the clipped screen, when Ubuntu boots back up, I get GRUB. I let it load Ubuntu, then I see a text-based interface, where I can then enter the boot password.

This isn't an ideal solution, but at least I can boot.

I reported this bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cryptsetup/+bug/1396227.