# First Time Installing Ubuntu Server. Need Some Help

Tags: server, grub2, system-installation

**I'm attempting to install Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS** (this system was running Ubuntu Desktop 16.014 LTS just fine).

I installed from USB to the single hard disk on this computer. Then at Software Selection I just select Standard System Utilities, OpenSSH and Basic Ubuntu Server.

**The goal** of the server is to just be a simple File Server on my local network.

**The issue** I'm having is after I successfully install, I reboot and after POST all I see is a blinking cursor, and it doesn't seem to take or respond to any keyboard input.

Is GRUB not loading? Or am I missing something? What could be the issue? I haven't made any BIOS changes since it was running the desktop version.

Comment: You coul have kept the desktop version and easily install the same tools if required, for any type of server you need. And if you need to share folder(s) from that to your home network, it takes no more than right-click > share. It will ask to install some samba packages.

Comment: For sure. I did that first actually to see if I could do it, as I'm a nub to Linux. But my end-game goal is to get a true server going with no gui, and ssh in from another computer. Once I get ssh going I'm going to take that keyboard, mouse, monitor and gfx card off/out and put all that on a desktop.

Comment: I am able to ssh into the server, I've discovered. So... I was expecting a login screen locally from the server.  Should I?.. Or is there something I need to install or enable to get a  login screen at the server itself?

Answer (score 1):

**The answer is "...access tty console (by pressing Ctrl+Alt +F*, where F* is any F1 - F6 key)..."** ([Ubuntu 14.10 booting problems - no login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/542012/ubuntu-14-10-booting-problems-no-login-screen#542490))

I suggest they should mention that here: Install Ubuntu Server Tutorial https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-server#11 or Ubuntu Server Guide https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/

Maybe I missed it lol?