# Having problem with opening softwares from the terminal (including wireshark & gedit)

Tags: command-line, 14.10, gedit, wireshark, mir

I am using Ubuntu 14.10 and I am having errors opening softwares from the terminal. For example:

```
build@build:/usr/local/bin$ sudo wireshark
gdk_mir_display_open
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory

(wireshark:4309): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

and

```
build@build:~$ sudo gedit &
[1] 4321
build@build:~$ gdk_mir_display_open
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory

(gedit:4322): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

I was not able to find any solution for these kind of errors on the internet. Kindly help out!

Comment: Your issues are related to the display manager Mir, not the applications. refer to the rebuild instructions here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/541926/blank-screen-on-tty7-after-upgrading-from-14-04-to-14-10

Comment: Hi Steve, the solution in the questions you gave are related to the Gnome, right now I am using Unity.  If you know the solution related to Unity, please share